# Поиск строк в массиве объектов

Tags: python-2.x, python-2.7

Как найти, например, имя или телефон в этом массиве объектов?

```
import shutil
import os


class Database:

    name = 'n/a'
    phone = 'n/a'
    list = []
    copy_list = []


    class Rec:
        def __init__(self, nam, phon):
            self.name = nam
            self.phone = phon

        def __str__(self):
            return "%s is a %s" % (self.name, self.phone)

    def __init__(self, fileName):
        self.my_file = open (fileName, 'a+')
        #self._load()


    def addRecord(self, name, phone):
        self.list.append(Database.Rec(name,phone))

    def save(self):
        for item in self.list:
            self.my_file.write("%s" % item)

    def out(self):
        print '\n'.join(str(item) for item in self.list)


    def delete(self, number):
        self.copy_list = self.list[:]# copy for recovery
        del self.list[number]


    def findByName(self, name):
        return None

    def findByPhone(self, phone):
        phon1 = phone
        if phon1 in self.list:
            return phon1
        else: print ("Sorry, try again")

    def _load(self):
        #self.list_rec = self.my_file.readlines()
        #self.list.append(self.list_rec)
        #print (''.join(self.list))
        pass

#---------------------------------------------
def fun_input():
    print ("Please enter the name")
    name = raw_input()
    print ("Please enter phone number")
    phone = raw_input()
    db.addRecord(name, phone)
    #db.save()

def fun_output():
    db.out()

def fun_find():
    print ("Please enter the phone number for find:")
    ph = raw_input()
    db.findByPhone(ph)


def fu_delete():
    db.out()
    print ("Please choose item for delete")
    number = int(raw_input())
    db.delete(number)

def fu_exit():
    db.save()
    db.my_file.close()
    exit()

def fu_recovery():
    db.list = db.copy_list[:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
def findByName(self, name):
    res = self.findSubStr(name)
    if len(res) == 0:
        print ("Sorry, nothing match in names for " + name)
    return res

def findByPhone(self, phone):
    res = self.findSubStr(phone)
    if len(res) == 0:
        print ("Sorry, nothing match in phones for " + phone)
    return res

def findSubStr(self, substr):
    res = []
    for el in self.list:
        if substr in el:
            res.append(el)
    return res
```

Comment: У меня выскакивает ошибка:                                                                  _File "D:\Python\Programa2.py", line 72, in findSubStr
    if substr in el:
TypeError: argument of type 'instance' is not iterable_